# The postfix module does not support the Debian family of operating systems

Tags: vagrant, puppet, postfix-mta

I have a vagrant and virtual box configuration and I tried installing postfix using puphet but I can't proceed because I always encounter this error when I run vagrant up or vagrant provision

```
Info: Loading facts in /etc/puppet/modules/rabbitmq/lib/facter/rabbitmq_erlang_cookie.rb
Warning: Could not retrieve fact fqdn
Error: The postfix module does not support the Debian family of operating systems. on node teaser-site-mgr
Error: The postfix module does not support the Debian family of operating systems. on node teaser-site-mgr
The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!

FACTER_ssh_username='vagrant' puppet apply --verbose --hiera_config /vagrant/puphpet/puppet/hiera.yaml --parser future --manifestdir /tmp/vagrant-puppet/manifests --detailed-exitcodes /tmp/vagrant-puppet/manifests/manifest.pp || [ $? -eq 2 ]

Stdout from the command:
```

and in my manifest.pp

```
class {'postfix':
  remove_sendmail => false,
  myorigin      =>  undef,
  relayhost     => undef,
  relayhost_port  => undef,
}
```

I also added this mod in Puppetfile

```
mod 'postfix', :git => 'https://github.com/Aethylred/puppet-postfix'
```

Please help anyone m(_ _)m

Comment: Can you make vagrant **not** use `--parser future`? I just don't see how it's necessary, and there is a marginal chance that it's causing your issues.

Answer (score 0):

@felix-frank `--parser future` is def. required by PuPHPet. Please don't remove this.

@inferno, the issue is you're trying to use this puppet-postfix module in a Debian OS, when it clearly states it does not support Debian.

Might I suggest https://github.com/example42/puppet-postfix ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the error(s) I encountered is also somehow my fault.
Its because the puppet version now in my vagrant is 3.5.x (i created the config months ago) and i didn't noticed that the puphpet.com config has been also updated 
and also the required puppet version is just 3.4.x
So when I run `vagrant provision`, the puppet version is updated to latest version which is 3.5.x (because of outdated puphpet config) thats why I always encounter the error (and sometimes syntax error)


im just wondering why puppet version 3.0 to 3.5 is now unsupported (but still puphpet.com is using it for vagrant) http://docs.puppetlabs.com/release_notes/


But anyways, thank you very much for your help guys :) I won't notice my mistake without all of your help m(_ _)m